# Lost power cell during game play

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

On Horizon Zero Dawn I have gone back for the 1st power cell and it's not there. I believe I have picked it up but mistakenly dropped it during game play when my items were full, and I wanted to pick up other items.

How can I find the lost power cell?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the power cells are key items and cannot be dropped or sold

Comment: I have gone back for the 1st power cell and it is not there. I have tried several times restarted and nothing works.

Comment: I am at level 40 and thought I should go back for the armor but no luck.

Comment: First off, welcome to Arqade! If it's not in the first location, then you must have already acquired the power cell from this location. Have you checked the other locations outlined in the linked question?

Comment: On the quest it shows I have zero power cells so what makes you sure I have acquired a power cell??

Answer (score 0):

The power cells cannot be dropped, sold, or "lost". Following the [Ancient Armory](https://horizon.fandom.com/wiki/Ancient_Armory) questline, all power cells can be obtained, but they must *all* be obtained before you can unlock the armor; which only becomes available in the end-game.

Note: one is "missable"; this is part of a main quest line and while it is hard to miss, if you *don't* grab it when you are there, the area is inaccessible afterwards.

> ### Third Cell
>
> The third cell is in the Maker's End ruin, which you will visit as part of the Maker's End main quest. Climb all the way to the very top of the ruins to Ted Faro's office. Once there, instead of following the quest objective and examining the data storage system, turn around and find the yellow handholds leading up the ruined sky scraper. Follow these all the way to the top and find the Power Cell there. Use the rappel point to return to Ted Faro's office and continue the quest.

The rest of the cells can be collected at any point; you just need to progress the story line to unlock the areas they can be found if first.

Comment: So if I don't obtain the power cell at the time of the mission and when I go back and its not there what could I do to obtain it again?  I have no way of obtaining the armor anymore?

Comment: That power cell in particular can only be accessed during that mission, because the area becomes inaccessible afterwards. The item doesn't disappear

Comment: If you're sure you did get the power cell, and it's not in your inventory anymore, then it's a glitch

Comment: It is possible to get the back up to the top of Maker's End after the mission, in fact a faster path is made available. I missed it on the first playthrough and got it later.